# PDO insert só executa uma vez

Tags: php, pdo

estou estudando `PDO` para poder refazer as funções de um crud que utilizo em `mysqli`, porem estou com um problema, quando faço um insert com essa função a primeira vez ele insere o valor no banco, mas se chamo a função novamente ele ele só retorna false e não insere o valor, essa é a função:

```
public function getConnection() {

    $this->dbConn = null;

    try {
        $this->dbConn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->dbHost.';dbname='.$this->dbName, $this->dbuser, $this->dbPass );
        $this->dbConn->exec('Set names utf8');

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $this->dbConn;
}

function PDOCreate( $table, array $data, $ReturnId = false ) {

    $fields = implode(',', array_keys($data));
    $values = "'".implode("', '", $data)."'";

    $field = "";

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $field .= "$key=:$key, ";
    }

    $field = trim($field, ', ');

    $query = "INSERT INTO {$table} SET $field";

    $stmt = $this->getConnection()->prepare( $query );

    foreach ($data as $key => &$value) {
        $stmt->bindParam( $key, $value );
    }

    if( $ReturnId && $stmt->execute() ) {
        return $this->dbConn->lastInsertId();
    } else {
        return $stmt->execute();
    }       
}
```

para chamar essa função estou fazendo assim: `PDOCreate('lojas', array("id" => 2, "nome"=> "teste"));`

Comment: O título da pergunta já está estranho não bate com a descrição e o mais importante você tem duas chamadas do `execute()` no código 1)`if( $ReturnId && $stmt->execute() ) ` e 2) `$stmt->execute();`. Não deu para entender bem qual é o problema mas aquele if no final precisa ser estruturado melhor.

Comment: mesmo se eu chamar a função varias vezes ele só executa 1 vez (e para executar de novo eu tenho que deletar a linha inserida no banco)

Comment: Tem algum campo como auto increment ou algum campo como unique key? veja se o `execute()` pega algum erro

Comment: sim, nessa tabela o campo ID é auto_increment e tem dois campos unique

Comment: `execute()` apenas retorna false

Comment: Se vc tenta incluir duas vezes o mesmo registro a unique key vai barrar. Deixe seu código assim: `if(!$stmt->execute()){ echo '<pre>'; print_r($stmt->errorInfo());}` assim exibira a mensagem de erro.

Comment: você esta certo! @rray duplicate key! vlw

Comment: mas como posso tratar essas exceções?

Comment: Com `$stmt->errorInfo()[0]` de acordo com http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.errorinfo.php